# Rxjs like operator that acts like a for loop

Tags: angular, rxjs

I really enjoy rxjs, and I am looking to do something that seems a bit unconventional ( at least I haven't found anything about it yet ), but basically, I am trying to create an Observable that acts like a for loop for getting values from my database, which consists of getting data from a set of users (which could be any number of users).

Currently my for-loop is structured like so:

```
for(let friend of user.friends) {
  this.postsSub = this.feedService.getPosts(friend.uid).map(friendPosts => {
    for(let post of friendPosts){
      this.posts.push(post);
    }
    this.feeds = this.feedService.sortAndReverse(this.posts);
  }).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe();
}
```

But I am not sure how to translate this into an Observable that will emit values over time, for each individual friend's posts in a usable manner for the Feed. Right now this just seems really inefficient, but it could be the best that I can do right now (hopefully not).

In the future, the idea would be that I would only display the first 10 posts (chronologically, based on their timestamp), and then when the user reaches the end of the page, it would display the next batch (but that seems like another question for another day). Right now though it just retrieves every post from every friend that is friends with the user.

***Edit with more information***

```
    userId1Feed: { 

    postId1: { friend1, etc...}
    postId2: {friend2, etc...}
    postId3: {friend1, etc...}
    postId4: {friend1, etc...}
    postId5: {friend3, etc...}
    postId6: {friend2, etc...}
}
```

So that it would get all of the posts of people that are friends with `<userId1>`

Comment: You mean, you want to have an update when a friend publishes a post?

Comment: @ManzurKhan I updated the post to include more information. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Posts are something that are dependent on the outside world, i.e when your friend publishes the post. You can't have an observable that can detect the outside world change. You have to ping the server to get the latest post everytime. 
The only other way I can think of is firebase realtime database. I haven't actually use it myself, but if it's your hobby project and you really want to do it that way, you should check that out

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Firestore and AngularFire2, and I can get the user's posts dynamically just fine, I just was looking for a more efficient way to get it using rxjs and observables, using something like combineLatest or something, but thanks for the help!